# Avoid regeneration of parent node if it is already exist in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using **XSLT** in PHP codeigniter framework to change format of XML.

**Input is like**

```
<data>
   <person_name>value</person_name>
   <person_address>value</person_address>
   <person_bloodGroup>value</person_bloodGroup>
   <person_weight>value</person_weight>
</data>
```

and **I want to convert it into**

```
<data>
  <frm:details>
      <d:name>value</d:name>
      <d:address>value</d:address>
  </frm:details>
  <frm:health>
      <d:bloodGroup>value</d:bloodGroup>
      <d:weight>value</d:weight>
  </frm:health>
</data>
```

I am using XSLT as

```
<xsl:template match="person_name">
    <frm:details>
        <d:name>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </d:name>
    </frm:details>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_address">
    <frm:details>
        <d:address>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </d:address>
    </frm:details>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_bloodGroup">
    <frm:health>
        <d:bloodGroup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </d:bloodGroup>
    </frm:health>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_address">
    <frm:health>
        <d:weight>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </d:weight>
    </frm:health>
</xsl:template>
```

But it generates frm:details tag two times separately for name and address. I am not familiar with XSLT. IS there any way so I can check if parent node already exist then add child node in it without regenerating parent node. **I am getting output as**

```
<frm:details>
    <d:name>value</d:name>
</frm:details>

<frm:details>
    <d:address>value</d:address>
</frm:details>

<frm:health>
    <d:bloodGroup>value</d:bloodGroup>
</frm:health>

<frm:health>
    <d:weight>value</d:weight>
</frm:health>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We need to see the parent element of `person_name` and `person_address` in your input, and how  your current XSLT handles it.

Comment: Original XML is too large and confidential to share. I just created similar scenario. but   person_name and person_address will come under single node. can be considered as data node. No nested nodes are used in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a template matching the `data` node and create the parent elements there. Then apply the templates handling the relevant child nodes (and remove the creation of parent from these):

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <frm:details>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person_name | person_address"/>
        </frm:details>
        <frm:health>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person_bloodGroup | person_weight"/>
        </frm:health>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_name">
    <d:name>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </d:name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_address">
    <d:address>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </d:address>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_bloodGroup">
    <d:bloodGroup>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </d:bloodGroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person_weight">
    <d:weight>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </d:weight>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <frm:details>
            <d:name>
                <xsl:value-of select="person_name"/>
            </d:name>
            <d:address>
                <xsl:value-of select="person_address"/>
            </d:address>
        </frm:details>
        <frm:health>
            <d:bloodGroup>
                <xsl:value-of select="person_bloodGroup"/>
            </d:bloodGroup>
            <d:weight>
                <xsl:value-of select="person_weight"/>
            </d:weight>
        </frm:health>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks you. But there are many more nodes in input which I dont want to add in frm:details. They will come under different parent node. If I apply XSLT like above then all nodes will come under frm:details node. All the nodes in input are under data node

Comment: "*If I apply XSLT like above then all nodes will come under frm:details node.*" No, only those that are under the same `data` parent node. If you don't want all of them, then apply templates selectively only to those that you do want.

Comment: All nodes are in data. there is only one parent node for all elements

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by "*They will come under different parent node.*" In any case, if you want only `person_name` and `person_address`, then do `<xsl:apply-templates select="person_name | person_address"/>` in the template matching `data`.

Comment: I updated question. In input XML only one parent node and in output XML it is having two nodes details and health